# What are the rules for Storm Giants?

Tags: warhammer-40k

When I started looking up *Warhammer 40k*, I had selected the regular Space Marine book and a few models as a reference. After finding out how incredibly powerful scouts could become, I decided that a good chunk of my forces would be scouts; luckily, I found a specific chapter online that did just that: [**Storm Giants**](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Giants). Unfortunately, I found out later that Storm Giants are not a selectable chapter in the Codex, only the vastly different [**Storm Lords**](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Storm_Lords). So, considering that specific chapters in the codex get a bonus for every unit being from that chapter:

First, **Are the Storm Giants listed in a specific Codex?**

And second, **What chapter would the Storm Giants be considered as far as bonuses go?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the first wiki article you linked to, Storm Giants are most likely a successor chapter of the Salamanders, which means they should probably be played using Salamanders chapter tactics.  However, also according to the same wiki article you linked to, (in universe) the true founding chapter of the Storm Giants is unknown... The fact that it is the Salamanders is just the Imperium's best guess.  So really, the Strom Giants could be a successor of any chapter, and therefore you could use any chapter tactics you desire without breaking canon.

As Aslum pointed out, the references section of the first wiki page you linked to will give you more information.

EDIT: Aslum deleted his post... However, his advice about checking out the books listed in the references section of the Storm Giants wiki page is spot on. (should you want a physical book reference)

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it certainly gives me options if I can't find anything in the physical books!